# customize spinner style

Tags: android, spinner

How to customize android spinner like this, and also the item of spinner also will look like this width. Is it possible to do this? If yes means tell the way. Otherwise what will do?

[image: Spinner]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create 2 or 3 state 9 patch image for the `selected`, `pressed` and `default` state of the `Spinner` and then use them as `background` of the `Spinner`. 
Have a look at this [post](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/) which beautifully explain all the process.